# MySQL ...Starting crash recovery

Tags: mysql, crash, recovery

I have searched high and low for a solution to this problem. My MySql gives me the following readout:

```
121231 20:41:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121231 20:41:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
121231 20:41:05  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
121231 20:41:06  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121231 20:41:07 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 124716458
121231 20:41:07 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121231 20:41:07 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121231 20:41:07 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121231 20:41:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121231 20:41:09 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.27'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Everytime it starts. I've tried deleting files, dropping the database, running Magento's Repair Database Tool, starting all over with a new database but no matter what I get this error.

It makes me uncomfortable because I'm not sure something might get corrupted or IS corrupted. I'm using Windows Vista, and Xampp but I also was using nginX with the same thing showing.

I just recreated a brand new database and now after shutdown (which I have to do sometimes) the error is showing up again! Is this a normal thing or is there somehing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What i think the problem might be is .

give MySql access to the firewall fix this
you should allow MySQL server (mysqld.exe) to start and allow access to port 3306.
Try to decrease innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.ini file then. Set it to 1G and check if this will allow service to start.

Comment: Thanks. It starts fine. It's not having any problems starting. It has access through the computers firewall but not the routers firewall. I mean it seems to be operating great. I actually tried allowing access through the routers firewall and check it with a port checker.

Comment: try delete your log file ,after stopping the server then restart the server

Comment: I done done that multitudinous times! I'm sorry, but have you ever worked on a MySQL Database!? I'm looking for expert advice. Just joking. :)

Comment: Did you resolve this? I see these logs in my working mysql server on RedHat5 and just makes me un-easy.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the log InnoDB starts crash recovery:

```
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
```

The reason for that is MySQL shut down wasn't clean. Why? May be MySQL has been exiting too long and OS kills the process (if you reboot the server). Or MySQL crashes due to a bug.